# Displaying images and a text string simultaneously by button click

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jlabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display images on JPanels using image paths in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964639/how-to-display-images-on-jpanels-using-image-paths-in-netbeans)

I've prepared a GUI with buttons and Jpanels. When the buttons are clicked on in the JFrame, 3 things need to happen. Two large images (specified by a path from the Source Packages) must appear on two seperate JPanels, and a small string of text (that I will write) in an empty JLabel. The problem is that I can't figure out how I should write the button handling code. I also don't know if I need to implement some init components in order for it to work. Here's some sample code:

```
package db.SuperMarioGFX;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author speterson86
 */
public class EnemyGFX extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form EnemyGFX
     */
    public EnemyGFX() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     *
     * SuppressWarnings("unchecked"), followed by over 1000 lines of Generated
     * Code are below this, but not necessary to include in this code sample!
     */
    private void btnBeachKoopaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        /**
         * For 'Land[JPanel]' (Panel-container for a set of buttons, not for
         * displaying images)
         *
         * Note that "pbx" is short for "picture box". Unlike VB, I couldn't
         * find any so-called picture boxes when I was building my GUI in
         * Netbeans, so I hoped JPanels would be the next best thing to use for
         * displaying relatively large (roughly 400 x 400 pixels or less each)
         * images. Now, here's the 3 things I need to display on my EnemyGFX
         * JFrame when the btnBeachKoopa button is clicked on:
         *
         * Display "GFX01.png" in pbxDefaultBinFile[JPanel] 
         * Display "Yoshi'sIsland2.zst, Level #$106" text in lblSaveState[JLabel] 
         * Display "Land1.PNG" in pbxFixedBinFile[JPanel]
         *
         * So how would I go about making that happen?...
         */
    }
```

Comment: This looks [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12964639/230513).

Answer (score 2):

If this were my project, I would consider

- uploading the images at program start up (if not too many images and if not too large) and place into ImageIcons.
- displaying the ImageIcons in JLabels that are already displayed by the GUI
- In the JButton's ActionListener code, set the image JLabel's ImageIcon via the `setIcon(...)` method and the text JLabel's text via `setText(...)`.
- You can in fact use one JLabel to hold both image and text if the image and text are to be close to each other and in an appropriate orientation.
- Also, it appears that you're using a code generator to generate your Swing code, such as NetBeans' Matisse drag and drop GUI creator. Since you're new to Swing, I strongly urge you to set this aside, to learn to code Swing by hand first, and only later when you are quite familiar with Swing use the code generator of you desire. This will save you a world of grief early on.

If you need more specific advice, then as we've suggested before, please show us your actual attempt to code this (not a skeleton of generated code -- we need to see **your** code) along with a detailed description of what problems your current code attempt is having.

Comment: +1 for sound advice; also consider implementing the `Icon` interface.